# Better sound in winsound?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, winsound

I am trying to automate playing sounds using python's `winsound` module. I've come to the point where I can give the function any number of notes (whose names I've stored as frequencies), and a tempo in BPM. However, the default beep sound in winsound is very crude, and it spaces out in higher tempos (anything above 60 BPM).

Is there any way to use another sound instead of the default `winsound.Beep` function? I want to stick with generated sound through code (not mp3's or any downloaded files), because I have already stored various notes as frequencies, and have something to work with; all it needs is a better sound.

If winsound isn't the best option, is there any other way I could generate sound in python? I also have some experience with C++ and Java, (or at least enough for the purposes of automating the sounds), so are there any libraries to produce a better, and a more consistent sound?

Comment: Please don't tag more than one language unless your project actually includes more than one language. Asking for libraries and tools is off-topic (please read the [help/on-topic], so it doesn't leave anything on-topic in the additional language tags that you added.

Comment: I was just looking for pointers for better sound options, not asking for specific modules.